# NoReverseMatch for '' with keyword arguments '' not found

Tags: python, django

I'm using django 2.1.4 and python 3.6.7. When i try to run my app i have an error 
NoReverseMatch at /depotAnnonce/
Reverse for 'mesChambres' with keyword arguments '{'args': [26, 3]}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['depotAnnonce\/mesChambres\/(?P[^/]+)\/(?P[^/]+)$']

views.py :

```
class DepotAnnView(TemplateView):
        template_name = "base/depotann.html"

    def get(self, request):
        form = Annonceform()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        util = Annonceur.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id)[0]
        form = Annonceform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            titre = form.cleaned_data['titre']
            nbChambre = form.cleaned_data['nbChambre']
            superficie = form.cleaned_data['superficie']
            loyer = form.cleaned_data['loyer']
            bail = form.cleaned_data['bail']
            animaux = form.cleaned_data['animaux']
            fumeur = form.cleaned_data['fumeur']
            description = form.cleaned_data['description']
            id = Annonce.objects.count()+1
            ann = Annonce(id, titre, nbChambre, superficie, loyer, bail, nbChambre, animaux, fumeur, description, request.user.id)
            ann.save()
            return redirect('mesChambres', args=[id,nbChambre])
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form' : form})

class MesChambreView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "base/mesChambres.html"

    def get(self, request, idAnn, nbCh):
        reponse = request.args
        form = Chambreform()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form}, reponse)


    def post(self, request):
        reponse = request.args
        form = Chambreform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            loyerCh = form.cleaned_data['loyerCh']
            superficieCh = form.cleaned_data['superficieCh']
            ch = Chambre(Chambre.objects.count()+1, reponse[0], loyerCh, superficieCh)
            ch.save()
            return redirect('index')
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form}, reponse)
```

urls.py :

```
 path('depotAnnonce/mesChambres/<idAnn>/<nbCh>', views.MesChambreView.as_view(), name ='mesChambres'),
```

Comment: Sounds like an issue with `redirect` not matching the URL pattern. without being able to pinpoint the exact error right now, try https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2016/05/05/django-tip-1-redirect.html for a good reference and maybe try keyword argument instead of positional ones.It looks like your argument list was not used as you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for `redirect` expects `*args` and `**kwargs`. So you would write:

```
return redirect('mesChambres', id, nbChambre)
```